# Binary Editor for Visual C++ 2008 edition

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I cant find the option to use Binary editor to open a file in Visual C++ 2008 Edition. Is this not supported anymore. I am using the following steps to opne a binary file.

1) Ctrl+o

2) Navigating to the directory

3) open with

Cant find Binary editor option at this point.

Can some one guide me oN how can I open binary file in Visual studio

Comment: I bet you're using the Express Edition - apparently the Binary Editor isn't available in that edition. I think you'll have to use one of the many free hex editors you can find in your nearest search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael said it, but Binary Editor isn't available in the express edition